# Comparing Decimals (not floats) in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a test case with the following line:

```
XCTAssert(testVal == value)
```

`value` and `testVal` are both Decimals. In most cases the equivalence test gives the expected result, but not always. For instance

```
let value = Decimal(0xFFFF)
... do stuff that generates testVal
XCTAssert(testVal == value) // evaluates false
```

BUT, when I look at value and testVal, they appear to be the same.

```
(lldb) print testVal == value
(Bool) $R0 = false // the condition causing the test to fail
(lldb) print value.description
(String) $R1 = "65535" // what you would expect, given the init
(lldb) print testVal.description
(String) $R2 = "65535" // the same as value. Hmmm...

(lldb) print (testVal - value).isZero
(Bool) $R3 = true // the difference is zero, but they are not equal?
```

I checked all the attributes of the two Decimals and even the hash values are the same, yet they evaluate to not being equal. The only difference I see is that one is compact and the other is not. I don't see a way to force compaction, so I don't know if this is a factor.

When initializing with other values, like 0xFF, 65535.1, and a host of others, the tests compare successfully.

While this sort of behavior is typical of floats, it should not happen for Decimals, should it?

Comment: How are you creating `testVal`? It can be different from `value` where their difference is effectively zero, but they are not equal...

Comment: But those differences would show up in their descriptions.

Comment: Looks like you hit on it yourself with the answer — the values can have the same description but different underlying representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the answer not long after posting this: It does have to do with the Decimal being compacted. From the docs:

> All the NSDecimal... arithmetic functions expect compact NSDecimal arguments.

Once I added the line

```
NSDecimalCompact(&testVal)
```

The comparisons worked as expected.

Comment: `let d1 = Decimal(0xFFFF)`
`let d2 = Decimal(65535.0)`
`d1 == d2` prints true for me

Comment: That code will create two compacted Decimals. testVal was constructed differently, and was not compact, though it had the same value. The takeaway is "Decimal math is sometimes wrong if the two values are not both compact."

Comment: This is also what worked for me -> NSDecimalCompact(&testVal)!  Thanks!